# grok regex to get the string data from the last using a delimiter "

Tags: logstash-grok

I have this value when I had written a grok filer , sometimes instead of the last past of the string which is actually a server name it gives me few other thing. I there any way to cut the unnecessary things

pattern

" 48550 171 "apps~" "backend.k8s.us-consumer-uat.incominggateway" "usconsumeruat2worker085960.consumer.uat.sdc.icp"

I just want usconsumeruat2worker085960.consumer.uat.sdc.icp  as an output using some regex, not filter

I am expecting usconsumeruat2worker085960.consumer.uat.sdc.icp as the only thing